# What is the first function read by Drupal in a custom module?

Tags: bootstrapping

I've got a custom module working fine in Drupal 7.

In some pages, I have parameters in the URL that I'd like to get in order to perform certain actions.

For example, if a=logout or a=forgot_password or a=subscribe.

I'd like to know which function, in the mymodule.module file, is called first so I can check whether there's a special parameter and perform certain actions accordingly ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first hook invoked is [hook_boot()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7), if the Drupal variable page_cache_invoke_hooks is `TRUE`, otherwise is [hook_language_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!language.api.php/function/hook_language_init/7) (followed by [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7)).

I am assuming the module is not implementing alternative versions of bootstrap functions; in that case, the version of `cache_get()` implemented by the module is called first.

About `hook_boot()` keep in mind that:

- `hook_boot()` is invoked too early, when Drupal has not completed its bootstrap. This means that the only loaded modules are the ones implementing `hook_boot()`. Even in this case, your module can use function implemented from modules implementing `hook_boot()`, and already loaded from Drupal, which uses the following code.

  ```
  foreach (module_list(FALSE, TRUE) as $module) {
    drupal_load('module', $module);
    module_invoke($module, $hook);
  }
  ```

  If your module is aaaa.module, and it tries to call `zzzz_create_object()` (where zzzz.module implements `hook_boot()`) from `aaaa_boot()`,  `aaaa_boot()` will cause an error message about a not existing function.
- When `hook_boot()` is invoked, Drupal has not yet initialized its database, its Drupal variables (only when `$conf['page_cache_without_database']` is `TRUE`), and its session.

As consequence, the functions `hook_boot()` can call are restricted. For sure, the functions the hook can call are the ones that are part of bootstrap.inc, and all the PHP functions (with some restrictions too).

#### References

- [drupal_bootstrap()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7)
- [_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache/7)
- [drupal_language_initialize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_language_initialize/7)
- [_drupal_bootstrap_full()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_full/7)

Comment: in order to upvote this i'd have to dig into the docs and check it all out ...... but wow.

Comment: I added the links to the documentation for the relevant functions. `drupal_bootstrap()` is the function that bootstraps Drupal, and that calls the other ones I listed.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno! Is it "clean" to just put a switch statement on the $_GET variable at the top of mymodule.module file and than do the respective actions from there ?

Comment: @Axel You can do it in `hook_init()`, or `hook_boot()`. Just don't put code outside any function, in the module file.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I'm trying to create objects which are going to be global in mymodule_boot() but I get errors as though the object has never been instantiated. Does this function really always get called?

Comment: hook_boot should be called from your module, but is a real sledgehammer approach for initization (hook_init is, too).  You should really investigate a getter function in your module that initializes a singleton the first time it gets called.  IIRC, there are a few questions here about how to do that.

Comment: @Axel The only case when `hook_boot()`, and `hook_exit()` are not invoked is when the Drupal variable page_cache_invoke_hooks is not `TRUE`. Keep in mind that `hook_boot()` is invoked too early, when Drupal has not completed its bootstrap. If your code depends from other modules, those are not yet loaded, if they don't implement `hook_boot()`, and some Drupal functions are not yet available.

Comment: OK thanks.Your answer is correct as far as "the first function invoked" is concerned. In my case though, as you stated, I needed some variables from Drupal so I couldn't rely on this function. I thus created my own mymodule_boot_custom() function which I call at the top of the module and which sets up all my global variables/objects and stuff. Thanks for this crash course on Drupal's boostrap though! :)